# Align the green box with the grey box

Tags: css

I have a JS library, Vega, that given a div attaches a series of child divs representing UI elements concluding in a final canvas element. The problem is the canvas element will overflow and I'm trying to center it within the given div. I've provided a MWE that distills all my requirements.

Align the green box with the grey box with the following requirements:

- `parent` including padding has the same width as `user-div`***
- `element` has the same width as `parent` excluding `parent`'s padding
- `child` is centered relative to `user-div` (or `parent` including padding)
- `user-div` fits to the height of `child`

*** *Technically `parent` may be smaller as long as `element` does not change width and `parent` remains right-aligned, see below.*

`user-div` is used for positioning and sizing `parent`. `parent` is given to the JS library and will contain a UI element in the padding (set via JS) that must be within and right-aligned to `user-div`. The width of `element` determines the width of the `child` canvas, so the width of `element` must not be changed. `child` overflows and should be centered within `user-div`.

```css
/* Requirements:
 * parent including padding has the same width as user-div
 * element has the same width as parent excluding parent's padding
 * child is centered relative to user-div (or parent including padding)
 * user-div fits to the height of child
 */
  
.user-div {
  /* Uncomment height to visualize boxes
  height: 10em;
   */
  width: 10em;
  background: grey;
  margin-left: 10em;
  padding: 1em;
}
  
/* unknown: padding-right specified by library
 * requirement: width specified by user 
*/
.js-parent {
  /*
   */
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding-right: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
.js-element {
  /*
  position: absolute;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  position: initial !important;
  */
  height: 90%;
  background: blue;
}
  
/* unknown: width and height specified by library
*/
.js-child {
  /*
  position: absolute;
   */
  position: relative;
  width: 15em;
  height: 2em;
  background: green;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
  
.test-bounds {
  background: orange;
  width: 30em;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-bounds">Above</div>

<div class="user-div">
  <div class="js-parent">
    <div class="js-element">
      <div class="js-child">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test-bounds">Below</div>
```

You can see from my comments that I've come up (with some help) with 2 partial solutions with drawbacks. For example, absolute `child` means `user-div` collapses vertically. Absolute `element` also increases the width of `element` breaking the JS library. Both approaches explore removing elements from the flow. An alternative is to undo the padding of parent in element but I haven't figured any approach

Comment: It's me being obsessive about a very annoying JS library and I will accept a comprehensive answer that there is no solution.

Comment: Do you have control over the width of `user-div`?

Comment: Show your effort, instead of asking for a ready solution. Show specific errors you need help with and example output that you expect.

Comment: I have control over the widths of `user-div` and `js-parent`. I create both (not the others) but `js-parent` is controlled from js.

Comment: @Ron you can see from my comments that I've come up with 2 partial solutions but all with drawbacks. For example, absolute `child` means `user-div` shrinks but if you want example output just uncomment height on `user-div`. And absolute `element` increases the width of `element` breaking the JS library. Both explore removing elements from the flow. An alternative is to undo the padding of `parent` in element but I haven't figured any approach. The are no specific errors (this is a MWE) and for example output imagine the green bits sticking out of both sides from the grey, have the same length.

Comment: @user19087 I give up... After trying it, it is quite evidend that this is not some training excersise, but the way the question is posted, it does indeed read like one. You might want to edit the question as to not deter potential answerers.

Comment: @SwimmerF thanks for the attempt, and I've edited the question per your recommendation.

Comment: I am leaning towards impossible on the grounds that it seems impossible to center (without resizing) anything against a parent with asymmetric padding *without knowing the padding amount* no matter the positioning (float/flex/grid) or display (block,inline,absolute).